# Mysql PHP Cron for updating user stats

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm trying to build a php cron job that will run every 24 hours and updated user statics in a mysql database. The problem I've run into is I'm not sure how I should insure that the same users values are not updated in a loop meaning none of the others are updated. I was trying to do it with a while loop however it hasn't gone well.

So basically it should work like this
1. cron starts ->
2. updates each users stats in mysql database ->
3. cron ends

Comment: You need a flag in your database, like `last_updated`. Set it when you update someone's stats, then use a `WHERE last_updated < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` clause in your query/queries.

Comment: @Ravinder Thanks :) I'm going to use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySQL** solution:

You require MySQL `event` to run on a time basis.

And I suggest you write the `update` statements based on your condition and link the same procedure to the event scheduler you want to run on every day start.

You can do it as following:.

**Example**:

```
delimiter //
drop event if exists event_scheduling_sample;

create event if not exists event_scheduling_sample
--  on schedule every 86400 second starts 00:00:00
--  at timestamp( adddate( current_date, 1 ),'00:00:00' )
--  on schedule every 1 day 
    --   starts current_timestamp 
    --   ends current_timestamp + interval '5' day
--  on schedule every 1 day 
    --   starts current_timestamp 
    --   ends timestamp( current_date,'23:59:59' )

  on schedule every 1 day 
     starts timestamp( current_date + 1, '00:00:00' )

  comment 'event scheduling sample'
  do
    call db_name.procedure_name_that_updates_the_user_records();
;
//
delimiter ;
```

**Refer to**: [*MySQL: CREATE EVENT Syntax*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)

Default state of Event Scheduler is DISABLED.
You require to enable it by any of the following statements.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = ON;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1;
```

When the Event Scheduler is ON, the event scheduler thread is listed in the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as a daemon process, and its state is represented as shown here:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 1
   User: root
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Query
   Time: 0
  State: NULL
   Info: show processlist
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 2
   User: event_scheduler
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Daemon
   Time: 3
  State: Waiting for next activation
   Info: NULL
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Once the Event Scheduler is set ON, you would see it working.

**Refer to** : [MySQL Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html)