# MySQL syntax error in SQL scheduling query

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain why MySQL workbench complains about Syntax error at

`DECLARE @fil_name, @fil_path STRING;` 2 errors: unexpected '@fil_name' (at text suffix) and at STRING (missing colon)

`SELECT * FROM gumcad INTO OUTFILE @fil_path FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`  error at `@fil_path`: unexpected '@fil_path' (at text suffix)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT `Export` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
ENABLE 
DO BEGIN
    DECLARE @fil_name, @fil_path STRING;    
    SET @fil_name=CONCAT('GUMCAD-', DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%d%m%y'));
    SET @fil_path=CONCAT('C:/app/reports/gumcad/', @fil_name, '.csv'));
    SELECT * FROM gumcad INTO OUTFILE @fil_path FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; 
    INSERT INTO imported_reports (imr_est_id, imr_type, imr_create_date, imr_created, imr_record_status, imr_file_path, imr_file_name, imr_created_by)
    VALUES (2, GUMCAD, CURDATE(), NOW(), 'approved', @fil_path, @fil_name, 'SHEP');
END
DELIMITER;
```

**EDIT**

i just figured out that when using @var I don't have to use DECLARE. This is my new script:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT `Export` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
ENABLE 
DO BEGIN    
    SET @fil_name=CONCAT('GUMCAD-', DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%d%m%y'), '.csv');
    SET @fil_path='C:/app/reports/gumcad/';
    SET @export_path=CONCAT(@fil_path, @fil_name);

    SELECT * FROM gumcad INTO OUTFILE @export_path FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; 
    INSERT INTO imported_reports (imr_est_id, imr_type, imr_create_date, imr_created, imr_record_status, imr_file_path, imr_file_name, imr_created_by)
    VALUES (2, GUMCAD, CURDATE(), NOW(), 'approved', @fil_path, @fil_name, 'SHEP');
END
DELIMITER;
```

But then I have an error at `@export_path` `(unexpected '@export_path' (at text suffix))`, Can someone explain please?

**NEW UPDATE**
No more error message at the moment, I was able to run the script but one problem now is the script seem not to run every 2 seconds.

Please take a look at my revised script, I'm using MySQL 5.5:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `Export` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
ENABLE 
DO BEGIN
    DECLARE fil_name varchar(200);
    DECLARE export_path varchar(200);
    DECLARE fil_path varchar(200);   

    SET fil_name=CONCAT('GUMCAD-', DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%d%m%y'), '.csv');
    SET fil_path='C:/cellma/reports/gumcad/';
    SET export_path=CONCAT(fil_path, fil_name);

    SELECT * FROM gumcad INTO OUTFILE "export_path" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; 
    INSERT INTO imported_reports (imr_est_id, imr_type, imr_create_date, imr_created, imr_record_status, imr_file_path, imr_file_name, imr_created_by)
    VALUES (2, GUMCAD, CURDATE(), NOW(), 'approved', @fil_path, @fil_name, 'SHEP');
END $$
```

Comment: try to change `DECLARE @fil_name, @fil_path STRING; ` with `DECLARE fil_name, fil_path STRING; `

Comment: I tried. But the error missing colon at STRING can't be resolved. Also, as I know there are 2 types of variable in MySQL, procedure (without @) and session-specific variable (with @). The procedure variable would be reinitialized every time running the script. So I would need a session-specific variable here ..

Comment: **@TrungBún**: Can you please post exact error stack as thrown and *seen*

Comment: Think main the problem is you cannot specify variable as path to output file.  Please see example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548118/can-i-use-a-variable-to-specify-outfile-in-mysql

Comment: I fixed it. No more errors message appear now. The event is listed when I run query `show events`. But it doesn't work every 2 seconds ... Please see my update for information

Comment: **@TrungBún**: Is your event scheduler enabled ?? Read this answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431291/mysql-php-cron-for-updating-user-stats/22431509#22431509

Comment: It is enable, when I run script `show events`, the value of status column is `ENABLED`, type `RECURRING`, etc. So I believe this script should be running properly..